# Formulas for the Spinor Representation Product Decompositions $2^{[\frac{N-1}{2}]} \otimes 2^{[\frac{N-1}{2}]}=?$ and ...

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups, spin-geometry

We know that given the dimension $N$, we can construct the corresponding spinors for the $Spin(N)$ group (which has $Spin(N)/\mathbb{Z}_2=SO(N)$ so $Spin(N)$ is a double cocver of the spatial rotational group $SO(N)$).

Now, for a general $N$, I believe there is a
$$2^{[\frac{N-1}{2}]}$$-dimensional irreducible Spinor representation (irrep) of the $Spin(N)$ group. Here $[\frac{N-1}{2}]$ is the step function takes the maximum integer value but smaller than $\frac{N-1}{2}$. For example, $N=2n$ even, we have
$$2^{[\frac{N-1}{2}]}=2^{[\frac{2n-1}{2}]}=2^{{n}-1}=2^{\frac{N}{2}-1}.
$$
For example, $N=2n+1$ odd, we have
$$2^{[\frac{N-1}{2}]}=2^{n}=2^{\frac{N-1}{2}}.
$$

> **My question is that are there general simple formulas that can decompose the product of the spinor representations $2^{[\frac{N-1}{2}]}$ and their complex conjugation representations $\overline{2^{[\frac{N-1}{2}]}}$, say for the even $N$:**
> $$
> 2^{[\frac{N-1}{2}]} \otimes 2^{[\frac{N-1}{2}]} = N  \oplus \dots  ?
> $$
> $$
> 2^{[\frac{N-1}{2}]} \otimes \overline{2^{[\frac{N-1}{2}]}} = 1 \oplus \frac{N(N-1)}{2}  \oplus \dots?
> $$
> **For the odd $N$:**
> $$
> 2^{[\frac{N-1}{2}]} \otimes 2^{[\frac{N-1}{2}]} =
>  1 \oplus N  \oplus \frac{N(N-1)}{2}  \oplus  \dots  ?
> $$

For example, when $N=3$, we have:
$$
2 \otimes 2 =2 \otimes  \overline{2} = 1 \oplus 3.
$$
When $N=4$, we have:
$$
2 \otimes 2 = 4.
$$
$$
2 \otimes  \overline{2} = 1 \oplus 3.
$$
For example, when $N=5$,
$$
4 \otimes 4 = 1 \oplus 5 \oplus 10.
$$
$N=6$, we have:
$$
4 \otimes 4 = 6 \oplus 10.
$$
$$
4 \otimes \overline{4} = 1 \oplus 15.
$$
$N=7$:
$$
8 \otimes 8 = 1 \oplus 7 \oplus 21 \oplus 35.
$$

Do we have a formula for general $N$?

Ref/s are welcome!

Comment: Classic reference for representations of spin groups and Clifford algebras: https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/abs.pdf

Comment: thanks!!! --- but does this lead to a concrete formula?

Comment: p.s. I corrected some math typos/mistakes in my post.